# jQuery to bind data to ASP.NET DataList using a ashx handler

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ashx

Using jQuery how do I bind data from a call to a asp.net ashx handler to a datalist?

Comment: Ok what I have so far is:
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Handlers/ss.ashx?cId=' + 225,
            success: function(data) {
                BuildTable(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                //alert("error");
            }
        });

        function BuildTable(msg) {
            var d = msg;
 $('#data').html(d);
        }

    });
</script>

The handler is basically returning a formatted string of html.
How can the above be modified to return json object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer : You don't.  A datalist is server side and jQuery is all local.

Complex answer : You can use jQuery to allow the user to interact with controls and displays locally.  You can also use jQuery to update your data store (SQL).  Then you can reload the data into a server side varable from the data store inthe code behind.